# What is the best way and what are the differences to introduce a "pause explanatory" phrase inside another one?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons, dashes

In this example:

> bla bla bla *phrase such as **even if something like this doesn’t exist*** bla bla bla.

What can I use to inject my phrase in the middle of the sentence?

- ,phrase, (commas)
- ;phrase; (semicolons)
- —phrase— (dashes)

Comment: Please give a ***real*** example, probably explicitly showing the actual options you want advice on. What you have in your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

A *[parenthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_%28rhetoric%29)* is an interruption. It is a remark which you insert into the middle of a sentence as if you are interrupting yourself.

In writing, the parenthesis is separated from the interrupted sentence using punctuation. You have a choice of several punctuation marks. One of them, the *parenthesis*, is named for this use.

Here are the marks which are commonly used for this purpose in American English. I also give common American English name(s) for the marks.

- comma-space:

  > Bla bla bla**, even if this doesn’t exist,** bla bla bla.
- em-dash or space-en-dash-space (or hyphens, when en-dash and em-dash are not available):

  > Bla bla bla**—even if this doesn’t exist—**bla bla bla. (*[em-dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash)*)
  >   Bla bla bla**---even if this doesn’t exist---**bla bla bla. (em-dash using hyphen)
  >   Bla bla bla **– even if this doesn’t exist –** bla bla bla. (*[en-dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En-dash#En_dash)*)
  >   Bla bla bla **-- even if this doesn’t exist --** bla bla bla. (en-dash using hyphen)
- space-bracket, bracket-space, using any of the various [brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) invented for this purpose:

  > Bla bla bla **(even if this doesn’t exist)** bla bla bla. (*[parenthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis#Parentheses_.28_.29)* or round bracket)
  >   Bla bla bla **[even if this doesn’t exist]** bla bla bla. (*[bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis#Square_brackets_.5B_.5D)* or square bracket)

*[Semicolon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon)* (;) is not used for parenthesis. It is used more like a period (.), to separate complete sentences.

Style guides such as *[The Chicago Manual of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style)* will generally suggest the use of a particular mark for a particular kind of interruption. The square bracket, for instance, is often recommended when interrupting a quotation with an editorial remark:

> The witness said: “He [*the policeman*] hit me.” (Example from *[EnglishClub](http://www.englishclub.com/writing/punctuation-square-brackets.htm)*.)

Answer (score 0):

> The most common recipe for unicorn burgers—even if they do not exist—calls for phoenix eggs and mermaid tears.

Assuming you mean what I think you mean, I think dashes are correct here. Brackets would probably work as well in less formal writing.